# Not Receiving OTP Firebase Authentication message after my Toast Showing that "Message is Sent"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Application is working properly but the Authentication OTP is not coming on my phone number

Am I making any mistakes in the below code? I have also make the permission for the SMS and also the internet permission is there but I am still not able to get the OTP message on my device, **My sim is in another device**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    EditText editTextPhoneNumber;
    EditText editTextOtp;
    String codesent;
    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNumber);
        editTextOtp = findViewById(R.id.editTextOTP);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCallback = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                codesent =s;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message is sent to the Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

    }

    public void sendOtp(View view){
        String phoneNumber = editTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallback);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // ...
                        }else{

                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void verifyMessage(View view){
        String code = editTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        if (!codesent.equals("")){
            verifyCodeSent(codesent,code);
        }
    }

    public void verifyCodeSent(String verifyCode,String code){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verifyCode,code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly Let me know if I need to give some more information regarding the Code eg. Manifest or xml Files?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself some questions:

1. Are you working on a **emulator**?
2. Did the **first time** you implement the code and get the confirmation message consisting 
   of numbers?

**I will answer my questions and try what I tell you:**

1. It does not send a message to the emulator, but there is a solution by adding a default number and giving it a secret code. [image: like this]
2. If your answer is yes, Firebase provides you with one message if you remain on the same phone to shorten sending more than one message at the same time and reduce the cost, but if you do not send a message, he checks this process without a message code and does the required operation when barring from the phone number.

> I would love to ask you question number 2 so that things can be
>   clarified in the future.

Try this you can benefit:

```
       PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
            PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
            String numberPhone, mVerificationId;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            numberPhone = editTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

                       PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        numberPhone,        // Phone number to verify
                        60,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                        activity_main.this, // Activity (for callback binding)
                        mCallbacks);


            mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

            }

            @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull 
                PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                mVerificationId = s;
                mResendToken = forceResendingToken;

            }
        };   
    }

         private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          //  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "There was some error in Login in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The verification code entered was invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```